# Is it possible to to have checked radio without defiled data in VUE?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am creating radio buttons using the Vue's List Rendering, and I would like to have one preselected value, but without having a data set in the script.

Please see below code to get better understating of what I am trying to achieve:

SCRIPT:

```
data() {
   return {
       formData: {} //formData is empty by default, properties added on fly
   }
}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="switch-button-container two-items">
    <label class="switch-btn" v-for="o in data.formsData.departments"> <-- Data from json
        <input type="radio"
               v-model="formData.Department" <-- property and value added on fly
               name="departments"
               :value="o.value"
               :checked="formData.Department === 'Rent'"> 
        <span class="custom-radio">{{o.value}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this through JavaScript ?

Comment: "without having a data set in the script" I'm not sure what this means

Comment: @Goose I could probably have 'formData:{ Department: 'IT' } instead of just 'formData:{}'

Comment: uses `<label class="switch-btn" v-if="data.formsData.departments" v-for="o in data.formsData.departments">` instead, otherwise you will meet template compile error.

Comment: @Sphinx data is loaded earlier, so no errors. Anyways, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the initial state as rent like the following:

```
data (
    return {
        formData : {
            Department: "rent"
        }
    }
)
```

then when you iterate change to:

```
:checked="o.value === formData.Department"
```